# Editing JSS SXA route fields in Experience Editor

Tags: sxa, jss

Using a JSS site deployed on SXA 9.3, is it possible to edit route fields in Experience Editor ?
I have assigned simple fields to the route template and in Experience Editor I have tried using the Experience Accelerator "Other" button to edit the route template fields, however it just brings up a grey dialog box and the fields are not available. Is it feasible to use this approach ?

[image: SXA Other button in EE]

[image: Blank dialog box when editing route fields]

**EDIT:**
I've found that the fields that have been inherited as Base Templates are not displayed in the dialog, but fields that are directly added to the Route template are showing up correctly.

[image: Inherited versus template fields]

Fields on the App Route content item:

[image: Fields visible in the Route data item]

Only the field applied to the template directly appears in dialog:

[image: Only template field appears in dialog]

Comment: The fields exist and can be edited in CE and rendered in JSS. There are no errors in logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do it. As far as I can see, it is working fine on the latest code. 
Two custom fields in on the route template:

[image]

And they are visible in Experience Editor:

[image]

**UPDATE**: It is also working fine with fields inherited from a base template. Take a look here:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, must be my setup. I'll compare with the styleguide app.

Comment: Hi Dawid, I've found that it works with template fields that are directly applied to the route template, but not on template fields that are inherited as base templates. Any ideas?

Comment: @andyp It is also working fine with fields inherited from a base template. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks Dawid, looking further it seems that Content and Title are already in use further up the inheritance chain but don’t appear in the Inheritance list. Using other field names works fine.